# Retrieve a variable in Site.Master

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm working on an intranet (correcting bugs and adding features), what I need to do now is recognize if the logged in user has his `isAdministrator` variable set to `true` or `false` in the `Site.master` so that I can permit (or not) the display of the `Administrator` tab.

The `isAdministrator` variable is contained in the `Employee` object like such :

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
public global::System.Boolean IsAdministrator
{
    get
    {
        return _IsAdministrator;
    }
    set
    {
        OnIsAdministratorChanging(value);
        ReportPropertyChanging("IsAdministrator");
        _IsAdministrator = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
        ReportPropertyChanged("IsAdministrator");
        OnIsAdministratorChanged();
    }
}
private global::System.Boolean _IsAdministrator;
partial void OnIsAdministratorChanging(global::System.Boolean value);
partial void OnIsAdministratorChanged();
```

And is created (or filled) when I create a new `Employee` (that, at the same time, creates a new user to log in).

I looked it up and found about `View.Data` to get information to the `Site.Master` but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually using MVC?

Comment: Of course I am, is there a reason to doubt it?

Comment: Namely, MVC doesn't utilize master pages. You can work with Web Forms  within an MVC site, for backwards-compatibility, but they're totally different beasts.

Comment: That's very odd, I am an intern and I'm only supposed to debug / update it (and I'm new to the technology) - thank you for the input.

Comment: The reason I asked in the first place, is that having your question tagged only as MVC, especially when the issue most likely has nothing to do with MVC, is going to severely limit your answers. I would suggest either replacing the MVC tag entirely with or at least adding the Web Forms tag.